# Why, suddenly, will some laptop keys (e.g. F2, tab) not respond until held down?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I am using an HP 450 Probook G6. Until a couple of days ago the keyboard had worked perfectly since the machine was new approx 2 years ago.

Suddenly, the <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> keys have started failing to register intermittently - they seem to "go to sleep". This means that e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to change apps won't work. I've found that pressing and holding the key for approx 2 seconds sometimes "wakes it up". The key then works normally again, for a short period (usually 30-60 seconds). Then it will stop working again and I will need to repeat the process.

I have tried the following, without success:

- Checking all keyboard settings including e.g. sticky keys.
- Checking all language settings including 'input mode'.
- Updating the BIOS.
- Updating the keyboard driver.
- Reverting to a system restore point a few days before the problem first occurred.
- Searching extensively online for other suggestions.
- Stopping other applications and services to try to identify another process that might be interfering with key presses.

I am running Windows 10 Pro, Version 10.0.18363, with latest updates. I am not running any keyboard interceptor apps. I haven't deliberately installed any new software in the last week. Nothing is obviously wrong with the keyboard (e.g. spillages etc) and when the keys are working, they work completely normally, so I'm sure this isn't a physical problem.

Does anyone recognise these symptoms? Before I try radical workarounds like remapping keys, can anyone suggest anything I could try to diagnose or fix this?

**Further info**: using an online keyboard interceptor, it seems the affected keys are <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>F7</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and the <kbd>8</kbd> and - keys on the number pad. Once one of these starts working, they all do - until they stop all working again shortly afterwards.

Comment: Have you tried another keyboard?

Comment: Hi @David - no, unfortunately I don't have another keyboard! In the absence of a better idea I might order an external one, but I was hoping there might be other things I could try first.

Comment: @NeilT Not clear where you are located, but USB keyboards are fairly cheap and many office supply stores carry them. For less than $20 — often $10 in some cases — you can get one and see what’s up.

Comment: Might be just dirt, you could try to clean under the affected keys. Careful - look on internet (youtube) for guides for your model.

Comment: Thanks for comments so far - I'll get hold of an external keyboard and report back.

Comment: Thanks again for all comments. I got hold of an external keyboard which worked fine. The weird behaviour - where the affected keys suddenly come to life as a group, then later stop working again - has continued. Maybe it is something like dirt under the keyboard; at some point I might dismantle the machine, but for now I'll work around this using AutoHotKey or similar. I suppose the lesson is that if you assume something is a software-related problem but can't find anything similar on the internet, it probably isn't a software-related problem...